# Select which property to use based on the value passed into the method

Tags: c#, linq

I want to to select a day from a list and return it's values based on which day it is. I need the property in the comparison to be dynamic somehow

```
  void Check(string Day)
      {
          //This string holds the three day property prefix
          string subStrDay = Day.Substring(0, 3).ToLower().ToString();

          if (dayList.Exists(y => y.mon.Contains("True" + " " + Day + " " + "True")))
          {
              startWork(Day, userID, true);
          }
          else
          {
              startWork(Day, userID, false);
          }
     }
```

Essentially I need "y.mon" to be able to be "y.tue" "y.wed' etc. 
And no I can't just put the subStrDay variable there instead. Thanks

Comment: You could probably achieve this with reflection

Comment: *"no I can't just put the subStrDay variable there instead"* -- wuzza? Anyway, you need either reflection (slow, ugly, nasty, brutish, etc.) or a method on `y` (whatever `y` is -- do you know what data type `y` is?) that takes an enum and returns a property value. Just write a switch in the method. And your `day` value should be an enum, not a string. Don't leave the door open for some joker to pass "Oswald" for a day value.

Comment: As suggested above, there are solutions but this looks more like a code smell to me. If possible, you should take a step back and rethink the design.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've seen much worse suggestions on stack before so i thought i should clarify to avoid a silly comment XD

Comment: Juan has a point. What is the intent of this code? Maybe a total rewrite is the best thing.

Comment: @Juan and Edplunkett, Thanks for the suggestions.. I was looking at it from a strange perspective but with the help of the first comment below I added dictionaries and rewrote about 60% of the code, which relieved me from a lot of headache and unnecessary junk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1. Exactly what you asked for

Add this handy extension method to your library:

```
public static T Peek<T>(this object o, string propertyName)
{
    return (T)o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(o);
}
```

To get a day value based on a dynamic string, just call

```
var Day = "mon";
var s = y.Peek<string>(Day);
```

### Option #2. Amend class with property that takes a dynamic string

This is a more typical design and avoids the need to use Reflection.

You don't say what type `y` is but I assume it is a class sort of like this:

```
class ClassY
{
    public string mon { get; set; }
    public string tue { get; set; }
    public string wed { get; set; }
    public string thu { get; set; }
    public string fri { get; set; }
    public string sat { get; set; }
    public string sun { get; set; }
}
```

Instead, consider making up a new class `DayCollection` just for storing and retrieving days. So:

```
class DayCollection
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dayList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string this [string day]
    {
        get { return _dayList[day;}
        set { _dayList[day] = value; }
    }
}
```

Now your "Y class" is much shorter:

```
class ClassY
{
    public DayCollection Days  = new DayCollection();
}
```

Then instead of

```
if (dayList.Exists(y => y.mon.Contains("True" + " " + Day + " " + "True"))
```

use this:

```
if (dayList.Exists(y => y.Days[Day].Contains("True" + Day + " " + "true"))
```

This is a much better design if you intend to access day values determined by a dynamic string.

### If you insist on property-per-day

If you insist on having a property per day anyway, you can still add that on top:

```
class DayCollection
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dayList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string mon
    {
        get { return this["mon"]; }
        set { this["mon"] = value; }
    }
    public string mon
    {
        get { return this["mon"]; }
        set { this["mon"] = value; }
    }
    public string tue
    {
        get { return this["tue"]; }
        set { this["tue"] = value; }
    }
    //Etc....

    public string this[string day]
    {
        get { return _dayList[day;}
        set { _dayList[day] = value; }
    }
}
```

Thus the following two do the same thing:

```
var s1 = y.Days["mon"];
var s2 = y.Days.mon;
Assert.AreEqual(s1, s2);
```

### Now use a generic Dictionary

Once you understand how the above works, you can reduce effort by using inheritance.

You may notice that our DayCollection looks an awful lot like a Dictionary. In fact you could write the whole thing like this:

```
class DayCollection : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    //Nothing
}
```

If you want property-per-day just add to the class:

```
class DayCollection : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public string mon
    {
        get { return this["mon"]; }
        set { this["mon"] = value; }
    }
    //Etc....
}
```

Makes this very fast and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to follow your current path you could make `dayList` a dictionary with each key being "mon", "tue", etc..and then have the value be what ever corresponding string it actually needs to be.

You could then change your code to `dayList.Exists(y => y[Day].Contains("True" + " " + Day + " " + "True")`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit heavy, but if I understand you right and you don't have an option to modify your day class, you can build an expression:

```
    private static Expression<Func<Y,List<string>>> GetExrpession(string subStrDay)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Y), "y");
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, subStrDay);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Y,List<string>>>(propertyExpression, parameter);
    }
```

and use it like that:

```
static void Check(string Day)
{
    //This string holds the three day property prefix
    string subStrDay = Day.Substring(0, 3).ToLower().ToString();

    var exp = GetExrpession(subStrDay).Compile();

    startWork(Day, UserID, dayList.Exists(y => exp(y).Contains("True" + " " + Day + " " + "True")));

}
```